# Angular 4 display in next line for newline character for p tag

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a page in angular 4 where I have to display user comment list.Users may enter comments in multi-line. I would like to bind text in multi-line.I would like to display text starting by `\n` in the new line.

I have tried

```
<p [innerHTML]="comment.text"></p>
          &
<p>{{comment.text}}</p>
```

I don't want to replace `\n` with `<br>`tag.I want something else.

If it can be done on the binding side that would be great.

Comment: Why not use textarea? It will break line automatically as per \n

Comment: User input comments via textarea.Those comment lists are done using p tag

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Make use of `white-space: pre-line;` style. Add a style class e.g. `multi_lines_text` and add that on your `<p>`:

in your component css:

```
.multi_lines_text { 
    white-space: pre-line; 
}
```

and in your template:

```
<p class="multi_lines_text" [innerHTML]="comment.text"></p>
```

Link to [**StackBlitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ekkge7?file=app%2Fapp.component.css).

Comment: Thank you - this worked for me, with one minor variation:  I am using angular and I think it clears out '/n' therefore I used  '&#10;' instead and it works!

Answer (score 2):

You could try the pre html element.
[Link Pre](http://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/HTML/Textstrukturierung/pre)
Make sure the DOMSanitizer don't remove the line breaking, it will remove everything thats not secure.