# How can I separate data from one line

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I got simple Object which I get in such a way:

```
  getSelectedRecipients(event) {
    this.aliasesService.getRecipients(event.nr)
    .subscribe(
      res => {
        this.recipients = res;
        this.isVisible = true;
      },
      err => console.error(err)
    );
  }
```

and output of

> this.recipients

is:

```
{
recipients:
"one@domain.com,↵
two@domain.com,↵
three@domain.com,↵
four@domain.com
"}
```

Now I want to separate this data into my table.
Now I got inside something like

```
<td id="recipients">
{{recipients.recipients }}
</td>
```

and it's like: `one@domain.com, two@domain.com ... four@domain.com [button]`

But my point is to have:

```
one@domain.com [button]
two@domain.com [button]
.
.
.
four@domain.com [button]
```

How can I separate this?
I want this for updating query ( in next step ) that user is allowed to delete for example only three@domain.com instead of all recipients.

Comment: Do you want to keep all of them in the same `td`?

Comment: all of them in separated td

Comment: So it would also be different `tr`s (one table row per recipient), is that right?

Comment: yes with button, The main goal is to show all recipients and allow user to delete any recipients then again update mysql query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I suggest you build a pipe to split the recipients:

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'split-recipients'})
export class SplitRecipientsPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(recipients: string[]) {
    return recipients
        .split(',')
        .filter(Boolean)
        .map(r => r.trim());
  }
}
```

If you want one table row (`<tr>`) per recipient:

```html
<tr *ngFor="let r of recipients.recipients | split-recipients">
  <td>{{r}}</td>
  <td style="width: 60px"><button (click)="_delete(r, recipients)">REMOVE</button></td>
</tr>
```

If you want to keep all recipients in the same `<td>` element:

```html
<td id="recipients">
  <div style="display:flex;justify-content:space-between;width:100%;" 
       *ngFor="let r of recipients.recipients | split-recipients">
    <span>{{r}}</span>
    <button (click)="_delete(r, recipients)">REMOVE</button>
  </div>
</td>
```

Concerning the `_delete` method, in `ts` file:

```js
/**
 * Notice that recipients is the object that contains 
 *   the string recipients, and not the string itself.
 */
_delete(emailToDelete: string, recipients: any) {
  const newRecipients = recipients.recipients
        .split(',')
        .filter(Boolean)
        .map(r => r.trim())
        .filter(r => r !== emailToDelete)
        .join(',');

  recipients.recipients = newRecipients;
}
```

Comment: It works great but I got another problem. How now can I get clicked (Remove) recipient?
For example in my recipients I got 4 recipients and now I clicked Remove so now I want to got only 3 recipients. How can I do this?

Comment: Updated my answer with that.

Answer (score 0):

Use `split("\n")` to split the string by `newline`. and use `ngFor` loop.

```js
class A {
  getSelectedRecipients(event) {
    this.aliasesService.getRecipients(event.nr).subscribe(
      (res) => {
        this.recipients = res.recipients.split("\n");
        this.isVisible = true;
      },
      (err) => console.error(err)
    );
  }
}
```

```html
<td id="recipients" *ngFor="let recipient of recipients">
{{recipient}}
</td>
```

Update example for logic:

```js
const recipients = [
  "user1",
  "user2",
  "user3",
  "user4",
]
let deletedUsers = []
const deleteUser = (user) => deletedUsers.push(user)

const listUsers = () => {
  return recipients.filter(user => deletedUsers.indexOf(user) === -1)
}
console.log(listUsers()) // [ 'user1', 'user2', 'user3', 'user4' ]
deleteUser("user2")
console.log(listUsers()) // [ 'user1', 'user3', 'user4' ]
```

Comment: and then how can I chceck which recipient user deleted? Maybe should I build array?

Comment: u can go with the approach, where you don't delete any this here.. But instead create a deleted users. and filter those users while loopong.

Comment: check i have added a sample.

Comment: I got an error:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Comment: can you `console.log(res)` and see what is coming ... before split.

Comment: res: [object Object]

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(res))`

Comment: res: {"recipients":"one@domain.com,\ntwo@domain.com,\nthree@domain.com,\nfour@domain.com"}

Answer (score 0):

```css
#recipients {
   white-space: pre-line;
}
```

Basically, this question is dup of [Angular 4 display in next line for newline character for p tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48558106/angular-4-display-in-next-line-for-newline-character-for-p-tag)

Answer (score 0):

You can take your `recipients.recipients` and have it splitted with [.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) by what it seems to be the divisor character `,` and then proceed to use Angular [ngFor](https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data#add-logic-to-loop-through-data) attribute to render your array.

`const recipientsArray = recipients.recipients.split(',')`

```
<td *ngFor="let recipient of recipientsArray">
{{recipient }}
</td>
```